# Sending mulitple pics via email

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

How do I send multiple pics via email on my Android Samsung S5? It says only 10 pics can be sent... when they are attached and emailed... recieve error 'failed' as a result in the outbox. Is there a setting that needs to be turned on and if so where?